# SP Foundations 2013 workflow - copying data from source list to field in tasks

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

Greetings to everyone,

I am really putting my efforts in setting a sharepoint foundation 2013. One of my start workflows is leave request approval process, made from scratch in sharepoint designer.

In short - I am using 'collect data from user' to get the approval / rejection.
My goal is to ( after the task is created ) to copy there some fields from source list - mainly 'leave start date' and 'leave end date'. So the task will have it visible straight away, without 7 clicks.

The problem I encountered:

- Workflow pauses after 'collect data' line ( history logs inserted before - went ok / after - nothing )
- I tried to populate source list with ID of the created task - into some column, for future reference - failed.

I would really appreciate help in this issue. I found some tips use for this purpose output ID from the collect line?

Adding some details:

- the workflow is live and running
- I can provide some screens, if needed I will translate the PL comands

New thougt - it might be that the core problem is getting task id just after the task is created, and putting it the 'leave' list. Found some hints about parallel actions, side workflows - but no progress yet.

Thanks in advance,

Tom, Poland

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using "collect data from user"?  I would recommend a different approach. Simply leverage the out of box approval workflow on the list or form. It will automatically create the approval task and even send email to the approver for you.

EDIT: Sorry, I missed the foundation catch.  Here's some recommendations from a Stack thread on the same topic.

[SharePoint 2010 Approval Workflow in Foundation?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103903/sharepoint-2010-approval-workflow-in-foundation)

Comment: Thanks Cornelius, but I am after the step of making this workflow live - after reading a lot of the stuff you directed me to.                                                    The workflow is live and working, I just need to copy the column data from source list into the task list. So the row with task will also have mentioned dates. I did many tries with 'update list item' but failed - prolly due to to id issues, matching source and task items. ///.  Any tips for bypassing the pause after 'collect data', when there is need to do sth before end users complete the task? Thanks, Tom